# How to post data to the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller which extends `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` and I have a method

```
public ActionResult GetCategoryTreeNode(CategoryTreeNode parentNode)
{
    //to something
    return new ActionResult();
}
```

Where CategoryTreeNode is

```
public class CategoryTreeNode
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

When I call this GetCategoryTreeNode with [image] the value for parentNode.DisplayName is null and parentNode.Id is 0.

What do I have to change on the server side for it to populate parentNode with the values passed by the client?

Comment: Do you have the `[HttpPost]` attribute decorating that method?

Comment: How is your model binding taking place? show us some code of your view.

Comment: @neoistheone I tried adding [HttpPost] but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @Jatinpatil I am calling this through javascript not using model binding.

Comment: @JasonQuinn Ok then can you post your ajax call and how are you preparing and passing your data.

Answer (score 0):

I would add `[HttpPost]` to your controller action and if that isn't working try adding [FromBody] to the argument.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCategoryTreeNode([FromBody] CategoryTreeNode parentNode)
{
    //to something
    return new ActionResult();
}
```

Comment: parentNode still isn't populated with this change.